# how does the in-place calculation take place in C

Tags: c, io, in-place

I am working on a simple in-place fourier transform. But I do not know how does the in-place take place. For example the following code snippet, taken from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#C

As the function declares `void fft(cplx buf[], int n)`, without any output, how could the change in `buf` in the sub-function transfer back into the main function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>

double PI;
typedef double complex cplx;

void _fft(cplx buf[], cplx out[], int n, int step)
{
if (step < n) {
    _fft(out, buf, n, step * 2);
    _fft(out + step, buf + step, n, step * 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2 * step) {
        cplx t = cexp(-I * PI * i / n) * out[i + step];
        buf[i / 2]     = out[i] + t;
        buf[(i + n)/2] = out[i] - t;
    }
}
}

void fft(cplx buf[], int n)
{
cplx out[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) out[i] = buf[i];

_fft(buf, out, n, 1);
}


void show(const char * s, cplx buf[]) {
printf("%s", s);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    if (!cimag(buf[i]))
        printf("%g ", creal(buf[i]));
    else
        printf("(%g, %g) ", creal(buf[i]), cimag(buf[i]));
}

int main()
{
PI = atan2(1, 1) * 4;
cplx buf[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};

show("Data: ", buf);
fft(buf, 8);
show("\nFFT : ", buf);

return 0;
}
```

I am not sure whether I have made the question clear. I wrote a snippet below, with just the same structure with the one above. However, it does not work in in-place mode, by which I mean, the value changes of variable in the sub-function did not transfer into the main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void _sumab(int a, int b, int c)
{
printf("2: %d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c );
a = 2*a + b+c;
b = 12;
// if(a<800) _sumab(a, b, c);
printf("3: %d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c );
}

void sumab(int a, int b, int c)
{
printf("1: %d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c );
_sumab(a, b, c);
a = a*4;
printf("4: %d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c);
}


int main()
{
int out1 = 0;
int out2 = 1;
int out3 = 2;
sumab(out1+100, out2, out3);
printf("5: %d, %d, %d\n", out1, out2, out3);
return 0; 
}
```

in the former code, after calling the sub-function, the value stored in `buf` changes, even in the main function. but in the latter code, after calling the sub-function, the values of `a, b, c` remain the same, as they are in the main function scope. Why?

Did I left some important issue or something else? How does the in-place take place?

and if `fft(buf, 8)` means calculate the fourier transform of `buf` and store it still in `buf`, how about the expression `fft(buf+2, 8)`, it will calculate the fourier transform of `buf+2`, but stores in where?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off-topic, but a file scope identifier that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for any use. You shouldn't name your functions like that, or risk possible UB.

Comment: arrays are passed by reference, intrinsic types (like int) are passed by value.

Answer (score 4):

The key to your question is that in C, **you can't pass an array to a function**.

When you write this:

```
void fft(cplx buf[], int n)
```

The types in that declaration are **adjusted** <sup>*</sup> according to the rules defined in **§6.7.6.3 p7** of the C11 standard (citing the latest public draft, n1570, here):

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
>   *type*’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the
>   array type derivation. [...]

This means, the real declaration looks like this:

```
void fft(cplx *buf, int n)
```

So, you're actually passing **a pointer** and the function can manipulate the original array through that pointer.

---

***)** It's often said the array *decays as a pointer*. This is not the official wording of the standard, but widely understood. If you have an array like this:

```
char a[5];
```

and you just write `a`, this is evaluated as a pointer to the first element of `a`, of type `char *`. So, with a function declared like this:

```
void foo(char x[]);
```

you can just call it like

```
foo(a);
```

and what really gets passed is the pointer to the first element of `a`, therefore, `a` "decays" as a pointer.

Comment: Oh, then I got it. And how does the `fft(buf+2, 8)` work? so here, the number `2` is added onto the pointer or the value?

Comment: @RoyLiao `buf` evaluates as a pointer, so `buf + 2` is also a pointer (pointing to the third element).

Comment: @RoyLiao there are AFAIK only 3 operators in C that take an array operand (so the array doesn't evaluate as a pointer): `sizeof`, `_Alignof` and `&`.